# How can I control the drag drop logic when using the built in reorder cell accessory?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

In my app there are two approaches to reordering items in a `UICollectionView` which has a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list` layout.

- long press on a cell [which I expect experienced users to use]
- select 'Reorder Items' from a menu. This simply sets `collectionView.isEditing = true` and displays the reordering `UICellAccessory`.

I wish to ensure that items are only moved within their current section.

My issue is that there is a difference between how the two options are handled.
When a user long presses the cell I am able to handle my logic through `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDropDelegate` methods.
However, when a user selects 'Reorder Items' and displays reorder `UICellAccessory`, the cells can be moved without the delegate methods being called.

When a user presses the reorder `UICellAccessory, if they being to drag the cell before the 'press' becomes a 'long press' the delegate methods are not called.

I'm sure there is something which would allow me to enforce my reordering logic.

Thanks